# Getting denied when trying to write on mounted drive with rwx permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, raspbian

im mounting a network drive using the following in /etc/fstab:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX      /mnt/bilder     cifs    auto,username=XXXX,password=XXXX,vers=3.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Which works perfectly.
When I now check the permissions on /mnt

```
$ ls -la /mnt
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 23 13:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jul 12 14:16 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 pi   pi      0 Aug  1 15:04 bilder
```

then it seems like the pi user (was which I am logged in) has rwx permissions as owner. In fact everyone should have rwx.

But when I now try to touch /mnt/bilder, im getting denied

```
$ touch /mnt/bilder/test
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/bilder/test': Permission denied
```

How and why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real Windows file permissions are not shown when you mount a SMB share. What you see is merely what your fstab `file/dir_mode` options tell the CIFS client to *show*, but those options do not allow you to bypass the security.

(Windows/SMB file permissions are a bit more extensive than just `rwx` and would need different tools such as 'getcifsacl' to show properly.)

The actual access checks, however, are still done by the server according to file permissions set through Windows, and they're checked against the user account (`username=`) you used to mount the share.

Even if the server runs Samba on Linux, the same thing applies: all access checks are account-based, and although the client *could* show the real Linux file permissions (if it has a recent enough kernel which supports this SMBv3 extension), it cannot override them.

Comment: So u are saying my user on the remote server does not have sufficient permissions?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yes.